# Visual Studio Mac, build from command line?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, sublimetext3

I'm considering using Visual Studio and Xamarin to build a cross-platform app but I prefer to use Sublime Text as my editor. Currently I can't find any information on 3rd party tool integration with Visual Studio.

Does Visual Studio have any way to build from the command line like Xcode does using the "xcodebuild" utility? Ideally I want to make a shell script which can build as if I pressed the build button in VS and return errors I can parse and display in Sublime Text.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Another alternative to Visual Studio is JetBrains Rider.  I use it myself.

Answer (score 4):

We've use the command line like the following:
msbuild /p:Configuration="AppStore" /p:Platform="iPhone" /p:IpaPackageDir=bin/iPhone/AppStore /p:BuildIpa=true /target:xxxxxxx.sln

Finding doco for what options are required has taken time via Google.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I also found 'vstool' at "Visual Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/vstool" on Mac which seems to do a similar thing. Both are slower than building inside Visual Studio though and I don't see a way to actually run without going back into Visual Studio. Did you find a way to run?

Comment: We don't automaticically run the app.  We take the .ipa and upload to an internal web site for distribution to our test and staff iphones for testing or for loading to the app store if testing is complete.

Comment: with Visual Studio for Mac 2022, msbuild is the recommended and supported way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I use 'vstool' located at "/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/vstool" this way:

```
vstool build -t:Build -c:"Release|iPhone" "MyProject.sln";
```

As mentioned in vstool help:

```
Visual Studio Build Tool
build [options] [build-file]
-p --project:PROJECT  Name of the project to build.
-t --target:TARGET    Name of the target: Build or Clean.
-c --configuration:CONFIGURATION  Name of the solution configuration to build.
-r --runtime:PREFIX   Prefix of the Mono runtime to build against.

Supported targets:
  Build: build the project (the default target).
  Clean: clean the project.
```